# Crystal Reports Error-Subscript out of range

Tags: crystal-reports

I have deployed an application which uses crystal reports(8.0) runtime. The runtime files register fine during installation. However when I try to view a report on screen from the application I get the crystal Reports Error-'Subscript out of range'. The report however displays after the error message. This has never happened before despite having installed the same application using the same setup files on dozens of other computers running Win XP Pro SP2. What could be causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

Never seen that error...are you accessing arrays in any crystal formulas? I'd expect formulas to only error when the report is run and it sounds like the CR runtime simply ignores it, which may or may not be a good thing.